# the error of MPI initialization

Tags: c, parallel-processing, mpi

I have a question about parallelism. I have a portion of code which I have applied the concept of parallelizme and this part of code must be repeat N times in a loop, but I can not initialize the MPI in the loop because shows " MPI_Init(89): Cannot call MPI_INIT or MPI_INIT_THREAD more than once" and if I boot before the loop each process it will handle all the loop and it is not that the goal.

```
for (int i = 0; i <N; i ++)
{
the parallel area
}
```

I want that for every i in the loop, the K processes execute the parallel area.

Comment: Post all of your relevant code. It seems to me that you are mistaking MPI with OpenMP. In MPI memory is not shared (in the simplest case) and all processes are spawned once (in the simplest case), through `MPI_Init`.

Comment: the idea of my program is that I have N data wich the calculation results made on the given nth depends on the calculation results made on the (n-1)th data, therefore the calculation made on each data must be sequential, and for each data n I can divide it into sub independent data I can apply parallelizme.

Comment: Do you understand the MPI hello world example?

Comment: Is "the n-th value" an array?

Comment: yes is an array which depends calculation results made on the (n-1) th array, and on a data n I'll make parallel calculations.

Answer (score 1):

The canonical way to distribute calculations in your case is to run the loop in all MPI processes and make each rank except rank 0 skip the serial parts:

```
// Obtain the rank
int rank;
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);

for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
   if (rank == 0)
   {
      // Some serial calculations
   }

   //
   // Parallel part
   //

   if (rank == 0)
   {
      // More serial calculations within the loop
   }
}
```

If you need to communicate data produced in rank 0 in the serial calculations, you could either use point-to-point operations or collectives like `MPI_Bcast` or `MPI_Scatter` at the beginning of the parallel part. You could then bring the distributed data back to rank 0 for further processing in the second serial part with `MPI_Gather` or `MPI_Reduce` at the end of the parallel block.

Another canonical approach is to use the master-worker pattern where one process (the master) distributes work items to a set of worker processes that are simply spinning in a loop of *receive work* -> *process work* -> *return results*.

---

As to the multiple initialisation of MPI, one could check if it has already been done:

```
int done_already;

MPI_Initialized(&done_already);
if (!done_already)
   MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);
```

Note that once you finalise MPI by calling `MPI_Finalize`, it **cannot** be reinitialised for the duration of the current execution of the program.

Comment: I searched on the internet and i found that the MPI_Initialized is the routine may be used to determine whether MPI_INIT has been called, so what's the usefulness of MPI_Initialized in my case

Comment: I genuinely misread your question - the title is very confusing. See the updated answer. Also, may be you'd be better of using OpenMP instead.

Comment: in the example you cited, the loop and the parallel part will execute  by one of the process, so it is not that the goal.

Comment: No, the loop will execute in all ranks. Performing redundant operations is quite common in MPI. Only the parts enclosed within `if (rank == 0) { ... }` will execute in a single process.

Comment: what I want is that only the parallel part that executed by all processes and not the loop,
If the loop is never executed by the processes wholes going to give me a lag when I recovered the results for use in the next data

Comment: The parallel part is within a loop. How would you make the other processes execute it multiple times if not by having them execute a loop too?

Comment: i want to send you a document (.doc ou by letter) explain my case, but i do not know how, this is my email: san.chafik@gmail.com

Comment: I would rather have you update your question and express your problem clearly here. The reason I participate actively on Stack Overflow is that the answers could benefit other people too.